# How to replace the same character in multiple text files?

Tags: notepad

So I have over 100 text files, all of which are over the size required to be opened in a normal text editor (eg; notepad, notepad++). Meaning I cannot use those mentioned.

All text files contain the same format, they contain:

```
abc0001:00000009a
abc0054:000000809a
abc00888:054450000009a
```

and so on..

I was wondering, how do I replace the ":" in each of those text files to then be "\n" (regex for new line)
So then it would be:

```
abc0001
00000009a
abc0054
000000809a
abc00888
054450000009a
```

How would I do this to all of the 100 text files, without doing this manually and individually. (if there's any way?)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in Notepad++ in Search->Replace, there is a tab (Find in files) you select the directory, and fill "Find what", "Replace with" and click "Replace in Files" i think this will do it without the need to actually open the files, Note: you may need to use `\r\n` or `\n` it depends on the OS you want to view the file in (i think Windows uses \r\n)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`. The following does something similar to what you want. The question concerns Unix, but a lot of Unix utilities have been ported to MS Windows (even `sed`): http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

[UNIX: Replace Newline w/ Colon, Preserving Newline Before EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915556/unix-replace-newline-w-colon-preserving-newline-before-eof)

Something like (where you provide your text file as input, and the output becomes your new text file):

```
sed 's/:/\n/g'
```